# May I create a Facebook Page for a client?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

A client has requested that I see about creating a Facebook page for her organization - a nonprofit. She does not use Facebook herself, though I do. I am not a member of the organization, if it matters.

Is it possible, or even appropriate for that matter, for me to create and manage a page for the client? Will there be any way to transfer control of the page at a later time to a member of the organization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly possible, and appropriate to create pages on behalf of an organisation (or brand or product for that matter). It's very rare that a client will be able to manage their online presence, especially if they are none-technical : that's the reason why they employ marketing agencies after all.

Create the page via http://www.facebook.com/#!/pages/manage/  - be aware that in order to set the "pretty url" (e.g. faceboom.com/my-charity), the page needs to have a minimum number of people "connected to it" (fans).  Currently this figure is 25.

After the page it set up, you can add additional Admin users to allow them to control / edit the page. I guess you should therefore be able to transfer ownership by adding the new owner, and then removing yourself (though I haven't tried this so I can't confirm).

Answer (score -2):

Lots of info on doing this, but there are rules.

See this link for Info http://www.squidoo.com/facebookpage